# Why does having infinitely many negative degree terms in a Laurent series imply having an essential singularity at $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

**Question**: Why does having infinitely many negative degree terms in a Laurent series imply having an essential singularity at $0$?

**Why I am Asking**: I came across a question in Ahlfor's Complex Analysis book wanting us to show that $e^z$, $\sin z$, and $\cos z$ all have essential singularities at $\infty$.  I was going to write $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ in terms of $e^z$ and go about trying to show that, for instance, $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity at $0$.  However, I came across the above justification, and I couldn't quite reason why it works.... I was hoping that someone could shed some light on it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An isolated singularity is either a removable singularity, a pole or an essential singularity.  For a removable singularity, after removing the singularity you have an
analytic function, whose Laurent series is just a Taylor series: all negative degree terms are $0$.  For a pole of order
$m$, all terms of degree $< -m$ are $0$.  So if there are infinitely many nonzero terms of negative degree, it can't be removable and can't be a pole; all that's left is an essential singularity.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  Thank you so much!