# Classifying Singularities With Laurent Series Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently stuck on one part of a theorem in Conway's Complex Analysis book.  Namely, if $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$, then $z_0$ is a removable singularity if and only if $a_n=0$ for all $n<0$.

If $a_n=0$ for all $n$, then obviously $z_0$ is removable.  Now, if $z_0$ is removable, then $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z)(z-z_0) = 0$ so $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^{n+1}=0.$$ Why does this imply that $a_n=0$ for all $n < 0$?  Can you exchange the limit with the sum here?  If so why?

Comment: If it has a removable singularity at $z_0$ then it will have a power series expansion around $z_0$ and this expansion must be the Laurent series expansion also (because the latter is unque).

Comment: Okay, thank you.  What gives you the uniqueness?

Comment: @Isochron: See for example [Prove that the coefficients in a Laurent expansion are unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262603/42969)

Comment: Related: [Why does having infinitely many negative degree terms in a Laurent series imply having an essential singularity at 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3786602/42969)

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$, then $f$ is bounded on a (small) disk centered at $z_0$. Now write down the integral formula for $a_n$, $n<0$, integrating on a circle of arbitrarily small radius centered at $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an integration-free proof. Assume that $z_0=0$ and the series converges on the punctured disc $\{0<|z|<r\}$. By definition, this means both $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_{-n}}{z^n}$ converge on the punctured disc. If $0$ is a removable singularity, then $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$ exists. In particular, $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_{-n}}{z^n}$ is bounded on some sufficiently small punctured disc $\{0<|z|<\epsilon\}$.

Now consider the power series $h(z)=g(\frac{1}{z})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n}z^n$, which is convergent and bounded on $\left\{|z|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right\}$. Pick any $R>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Since $h(R)$ converges, $h$ converges whenever $|z|<R$. It follows that $h$ converges on $\{|z|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}\cup\{|z|<R\}=\mathbb C$, i.e., it is an entire function. In particular, it is continuous. Hence it is bounded on the compact disc $\{|z|\le \frac{1}{\epsilon}\}$. As it is also bounded on $\left\{|z|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right\}$, it is bounded on $\mathbb C$. So, by Liouville’s theorem (which is proved without using integration in textbooks that follow Weierstrass’ approach), $h$ is  constant. Therefore, by the uniqueness of power series expansion, we have $0=a_{-1}=a_{-2}=\cdots$.